# PHP unreference

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Lets say i have this code:

```
$val = 1;
$arr = Array();
$arr['val'] =& $val;
$val = 2;
echo $arr['val'];
```

This will print out 2, because $val was passed to $arr by reference.

My question is : if i passed a value to an array by reference, is there a way to remove that reference later on, making it a simple copied value ?
To make it clearer, i would like something like this:

```
$val = 1;
$arr = Array();
$arr['val'] =& $val;

$arr['val'] = clone $arr['val']; 
// Or better yet:
$arr = clone $arr;

$val = 2;
echo $arr['val'];
```

And this should print out 1 (because the array was cloned, before the referenced variable changed).
Howerver, clone does not work with arrays, it only works with objects.

Any ideas? I really have no clue how to do this. I tried writing a recursive copy function, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `unset` the index and then reassign by-value instead of by reference.

```
unset($arr['val']);
$arr['val'] = $val;
```

Comment: And how about, if i don't have the original $val ? Say i'm now in a different function and i only have access to $arr, and i want to remove all inner references.

Comment: @Kipras Then store the value, unset the array index, and reassign